# rails server on cloud9 IDE getting killed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide

Started GET "/" for 117.204.35.49 at 2014-12-28 15:11:25 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (31.9ms)
Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 91e7a7b071c4f0ff0a36637c7690af7832778cbe/custom.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 0cdc6737560e11ce2c9b4d52cd0d704ce82fd24d/_bootstrap-sprockets.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 0cdc6737560e11ce2c9b4d52cd0d704ce82fd24d/bootstrap.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_variables.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_mixins.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_hide-text.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_opacity.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_image.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_labels.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_reset-filter.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_resize.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_responsive-visibility.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_size.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_tab-focus.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_text-emphasis.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_text-overflow.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_vendor-prefixes.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_alerts.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_buttons.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_panels.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_pagination.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_list-group.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_nav-divider.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_forms.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_progress-bar.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_table-row.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_background-variant.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_border-radius.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_gradients.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_clearfix.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_center-block.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_nav-vertical-align.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_grid-framework.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 6e5e69eac2fc40f56bbeb5c941159c37154fa2df/_grid.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_normalize.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_print.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_glyphicons.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_scaffolding.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_type.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_code.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_grid.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_tables.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_forms.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_buttons.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_component-animations.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_dropdowns.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_button-groups.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_input-groups.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_navs.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_navbar.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_breadcrumbs.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_pagination.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_pager.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_labels.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_badges.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_jumbotron.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_thumbnails.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_alerts.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_progress-bars.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_media.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_list-group.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_panels.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_responsive-embed.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_wells.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_close.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_modals.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_tooltip.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_popovers.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_carousel.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_utilities.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 354166196ffaa1345b9396454028da0b5d60f8f4/_responsive-utilities.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #

Completed 200 OK in 9142ms (Views: 9118.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/assets/custom.css?body=1" for 117.204.35.49 at 2014-12-28 15:11:35 +0000

Started GET "/assets/static_pages.css?body=1" for 117.204.35.49 at 2014-12-28 15:11:35 +0000

Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 117.204.35.49 at 2014-12-28 15:11:35 +0000

Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 117.204.35.49 at 2014-12-28 15:11:35 +0000

Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 117.204.35.49 at 2014-12-28 15:11:35 +0000

Started GET "/assets/static_pages.js?body=1" for 117.204.35.49 at 2014-12-28 15:11:35 +0000

Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 117.204.35.49 at 2014-12-28 15:11:36 +0000

Started GET "/images/rails.png" for 117.204.35.49 at 2014-12-28 15:11:36 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/rails.png"):
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:22:in `middleware_call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in`call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`call_app'
  railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`tagged'
  railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in`call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in`call'
  railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in`call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in`call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in`service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in`block in start_thread'

Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (64.7ms)

Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 117.204.35.49 at 2014-12-28 15:11:37 +0000
Killed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677996/rails-server-on-cloud-9-ide-getting-killed/27681118#27681118

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment from Alex, the answer in [rails server on cloud 9 IDE getting killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677996/rails-server-on-cloud-9-ide-getting-killed/27681118#27681118) worked for me - just kill off a few spring processes, no need to upgrade necessarily.

Comment: Yes,the answer you mentioned worked for me also.Infact,that question was also posted by me.

Answer (score 1):

Processes on Cloud9 get killed when they run out of memory. By upgrading to premium you will have access to more RAM (1GB instead of 512MB). You will need to create a new workspace after upgrading to do so (for now).

Comment: Yup, can confirm this happened to me earlier today. I spent ages trying to figure out what it was, and it turned out to be a memory issue. If you have more than one rails app in your workspace, then you might want to think about removing one, or upgrading your account...