# rails server on cloud 9 IDE getting killed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide

I am learning ruby on rails from "Ruby on rails tutorial" by Michael Hartl.,I an working on cloud9 IDE.The problem is that after starting server,when I open the link on browser,server is getting killed.Some time home page is bring dispalyed and when i type another link manually,server is getting killed

Started GET "/static_pages/about" for 117.213.110.126 at 2014-12-28 15:44:08 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#about as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/about.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
Killed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to kill all spring process . First you can see all of them like: ps aux

and then you can kill like this: pkill -f "spring app", or by pid : kill -9 1111(your PID)

Comment: yeah.,I killed all "spring server" processes and now,it is working fine.can you explain me what these spring processes are and why should I kill them?

Comment: Spring is a Rails application preloader. It speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background so you don't need to boot it every time you run a test, rake task or migration. It could accumulate and slow performance. So you need to kill all of them time to time. You can find it in your Gemfile: # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'